# java dont' see CLASSPATH

Tags: java, derby

1) I have setted the variable `CLASSPATH` through `my computuer -> System variables;`

2) restarted the console and typed `echo %CLASSPATH%`, the `CLASSPATH` was setted and the value was:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\db\lib - this is where the derby.jar was and other related files
```

3) then I've typed `java org.apache.derby.tools.ij` and I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.tools.ij
```

I'am using windows xp, what I've did wrong?

Comment: You need to put the jar itself in the classpath, not just the directory that contains the jar.

Comment: Look at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\db\bin\ij.bat`

Comment: yes, but anyway I want to use the CLASSPATH to execute the ij, still getting this error even if I put the specific file name, not just the folder

Comment: wat version of derby jar you are using?

Comment: why are you running ij class expliclitly? You can run the ij batch file in the derby package instead

Comment: because I need to run the example from the book I learn :)

Comment: Then you can add derebytools.jar to the classpath and do the stuff you wanted as in below answer

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\t>java -cp %CLASSPATH% org.apache.derby.tools.ij
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\db\lib

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39653/discussion-between-ijp-and-targetcoder)

Comment: well, somehow now it works :), thank you for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add derbytools.jar to the class path and run the below command. ij class is present in the derbytools.jar

```
java org.apache.derby.tools.ij
```